# How do I run an exe file from cmd but in the same window?

Tags: c++, cmd

I want to run an exe file in the cmd.
After I compile a c++ file I want to see the executable, so I type `.build\bin\test.exe`. The first time it opens me a new cmd window

> [image: first time]

and when I try again it runs on the same window.

> [image: second time]

How do I solve this?
Thx

Comment: You need to open a cmd.exe window first. Then type the full path of the executable to execute it.

Comment: The first case is not your app running in a new window, it's just Avast freaking out and opening it itself. This is an exception, not a rule, so you really don't need to worry about it, there's nothing worth "solving" going on. Once a freshly compiled file has been run for the first time, Avast stops worrying about it and it behaves as you expect.

Comment: IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes thank you very much i didn't know that